# jquery: retrieve submitted values for name in array format

Tags: jquery

on submit, i need to collect the values for a series of checkbox fields with a common name in array format. i tried doing something like:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){   
  $(':input:checkbox[name=fields[]]', this).each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    console.log($(this).val);
  });
});
```

but the "[name=fields[]]" doesn't restrict the way i think it should.
what i eventually need to do is determine how many checkboxes have been checked from that fields array. i'm just sending to the console log while i figure out the conditions.

Comment: can you make a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net with your html and js so we can all see what you see?

Comment: Have you tried `$(':checkbox[name="fields[]"]', this)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){   
    var fields = new Array();
    $(':input:checkbox[name*=fields]', this).each(function() {
        index_a = $(this).attr('name');
        if (fields[index_a] == undefined) fields[index_a] = 0;
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) fields[index_a] += 1;
    });
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daybreaker/7UFs6/3

This will return a `fields` array with keys for each `fields[whatever]` and a value equal to how many checkboxes are checked within each `field[whatever]`.

In my jsfiddle example, I use `fields[opt1]` and `fields[opt2]`, and though technically probably not a good idea at all to have a key with brackets in it, it works. If you want, you could do some regular expressions to pull out the `opt1` inside and make that the key.

Comment: the field names are: <input name="fields[opt1]" />
so your second suggestion works great if I remove the name filter (except that it captures other inputs I want ignored), but it doesn't work with it.

Comment: your earlier suggestion was very simple and elegant. so i tried a combo of the earlier version with the revised:
count = $(':input:checkbox:checked[name*=fields]', this);
and it seems to be working. any gotchas that you can see?

Comment: It looks like that should work. And then the result array would only have keys for checkbox groups that have at least one box checked. Like I said before, one gotcha might be having an array key like `count[fields[opt1]]`, but it seems to work in Chrome at least.

Comment: found the gotcha. works fine in chrome and FF, but not IE (surprise, surprise). i'll try your second recommendation.

Comment: think i need to play with the earlier model some more. your revised code does too much. the fields array doesn't have duplicate keys -- i'm just counting checked elements in that single array. for example, the form fields are named: fields[opt1], fields[opt2], fields[opt3], fields[opt4] -- two of these may be checked, which should yield a count of 2.

Comment: this is working:
$('form').submit(function(e){
count = $(':input:checkbox:checked[name*=fields]', this);
if (count.length > 5 ) {alert('My message.');